# After installing Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows, I cannot boot it

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have Dell XPS 15 with Windows 10.
I installed Ubuntu 18.04 from a USB stick in a new partition. 
I got a message that the installation was successful.

Now, after I reboot and click F12, I see the following menu:

[image]

(where the highlighted entry reads "Windows boot manager").

When I click it, I get into Windows. 
I do not have any option to boot into Ubuntu.

I tried to switch UEFI on and off but it did not help.

How can I boot into my new Ubuntu 18.04 installation?

EDIT: my EFI partition looks like this:

```
EFI
|-- Microsoft
    |-- Boot
    |-- Recovery
|-- Boot
    |-- bootx64.efi
|-- dell
    |-- bios
    |-- SOS
    |-- logs
```

I do not have an "ubuntu" folder nor a "shimx64.efi" file. May this be the cause of the problem?

I tried to re-install Ubuntu from the USB while loading the USB with UEFI, but the result is the same.

Comment: @karel I tried this solution, but it seems to be outdated - at least 3 steps from the solution did not work (I commented below the answer).

Comment: I replied to your comment under the linked answer where you posted it.

Comment: I managed to run these steps but still cannot boot. Can this be related to the fact that there is no "ubuntu" in my EFI partition? (I added the contents of my EFI partition to the question).

Comment: Try this and if it doesn't work I'll retract my close vote: Immediately after the BIOS/UEFI splash screen during boot, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up a GNU GRUB menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the Esc key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen.

Comment: When I just click ESC several times after boot, Windows opens as usual. When I first click F12 (to get the UEFI menu) and then ESC,  again the menu closes and Windows opens as usual. Is it normal that I do not have any ubuntu efi files in my EFI folder?

Comment: I retracted my close vote.